# Looping pages for web scraping with R vectors of different length

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping

I am trying to gather data of jobs and companies from Indeed. My aim is to make a loop so that it scrapes a given amount of pages. The problem is that the length of the scraped vectors isn't the same for all, since, for example, not all job offers display the salary. Is there any way I could "fill" with NA values the corresponding spaces, so that the vectors are of same length?

```
listado = data.frame()

for(page_result in seq(from = 10, to = 100, by = 10)){
  link = paste("https://es.indeed.com/jobs?q=ingeniero+energ%C3%ADas+renovables&start=", page_result, sep='')
  page = read_html(link)
  
  title = page %>% html_nodes(".jobtitle") %>% html_text()
  location = page %>% html_nodes(".accessible-contrast-color-location") %>% html_text()
  descripcion =page %>% html_nodes(".summary") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
  fecha = page %>% html_nodes(".date") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
  empresa = page %>% html_nodes(".company") %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)
  listado = rbind(listado, data.frame(title, empresa, location,fecha, descripcion, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) 
  
 
  print(paste("Page:", page_result))
}
```

Comment: So what exactly are you "stuck" on? It's unclear what exactly is your desired output and what are you trying to change or what the problem is.

Comment: My desired output would be a single dataframe that gathered all the values for "puesto" and "empresa" for a defined number of pages

Answer (score 0):

Job cards don't all have the same structure, you can use job ids to walk along them with functions:

with a functional approach, you can replace a missing item by a NA_character instead and then all vector have the same length for one job card so finally for all jobs in a page.

I have tried not to change you code too much

```r
listado = data.frame()
library(rvest)

page_result <- 10
for(page_result in seq(from = 10, to = 100, by = 10)){
  link = paste("https://es.indeed.com/jobs?q=ingeniero+energ%C3%ADas+renovables&start=", page_result, sep='')
  page = read_html(link)

  job_ids <- page %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//*[contains(@id, 'p_')]") %>%
    html_attr('id')


  node <- '.summary'
  one_item <- function(job_card, node, trim = FALSE){

    tmp_res <- job_card %>%
      .[grepl(node, .)] %>%
      html_text(trim = trim)

    if (length(tmp_res) == 0L){
      return(NA_character_)
    }
    tmp_res
  }

  one_job <- function(job){
    message("---- ", job)
    job_card <- page %>%
      html_nodes(xpath = paste0("//*[contains(@id, '", job, "' )]")) %>%
      html_children()

    tibble::tibble(
      job_id = job,
      title = job_card %>% one_item("jobtitle", trim = TRUE),
      sublabel = job_card %>% one_item("iaLabel", trim = TRUE),
      location = job_card %>% one_item("location accessible-contrast-color-location", trim = TRUE),
      descripcion = job_card %>% one_item("summary", trim = TRUE),
      fecha = job_card %>% one_item("date", trim=TRUE),
      empresa = job_card %>% one_item("company", trim=TRUE))



  }

  listado = rbind(listado, purrr::map_df(job_ids, one_job))


  message(paste("----------------------- Page:", page_result))
}
```

In any case the website may check if you are a human with a captcha if you run this too often